# Как сделать большое количество запросов?

Tags: php, yii2, api

В базе есть 1500 записей. Нужно работать с API используя данные записи. То есть к API идет задача получить данные между двумя записями 1 и 2, следующий запрос 1 и 3, 1 и 4, 1 и 1500, 2 и 1, 2 и 2 и тд, пока не будет 1500 и 1500.

Получается что у меня будет 2 250 000 GET запросов.

В API есть ограничение на 15 000 запросов в сутки да и долго это ждать пока обрабатывается такое количество запросов по одному.
Можно ли как-то отправить за одни запрос больше одного условия или как это всё можно оптимизировать?

Comment: Добавить 2 синтетические таблицы с числами от 1 до 1500, и выбирать записи `between t1.num and t2.num` вместе с границами (чтобы различать). Вот только пока ты получишь ответы на все эти 2кк вариантов параметров в одном запросе, тебя уже скорее всего забанят. PS: А что, данные, что между 1 и 2, могут не вернуться при запросе данных между 1 и 3?

Comment: @Akina про таблицы подумаю, а вот вопрос не очень понял.
Если данные 1 и 2 получил, то сохраняю в базу, если данных нету, то след. 1 и 3 и тд